# jboss eap error org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection

Tags: spring, jboss, apache-camel, oracle-aq

I'm developing camel route to connect to Oracle AQ on Jboss EAP Fuse.
I managed to do it using the connection factory as follows:

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent" id="oracleAQQueue">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="oracleQueueAQCredentials"/>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter"
    id="oracleQueueAQCredentials" primary="true">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="connectionFactoryOracleAQAQQueue"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory"
    factory-method="getQueueConnectionFactory" id="connectionFactoryOracleAQAQQueue">
    <constructor-arg index="0">            
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:xx/xx@localhost:1521/orclpdb</value>            
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.Properties">
        <value/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What I'm trying to do next is to use the JNDI Datasource on the Jboss EAP instead of the connection string.
So I configured the datasource on jboss

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/AQ_DB" pool-name="AQ_DB_DataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclpdb</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>xx</user-name>
        <password>xx</password>
    </security>
</datasource>

<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>                     
</driver>
```

then I change my code to use the connection as follows:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/AQ_DB" />
        
    <bean class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory"
        factory-method="getQueueConnectionFactory" id="connectionFactoryOracleAQAQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="jndiConnectionFactory"/> 
        </constructor-arg>        
    </bean>
```

however, upon starting the Jboss EAP, the following error shown.

```
Cause: Error creating the db_connection; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:625)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.<init>(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:399)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.<init>(AQjmsConnection.java:259)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(AQjmsConnectionFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:181)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:411)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:396)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:927)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:901)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1079)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.getProviderKey(AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.java:99)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.<init>(AQjmsGeneralDBConnection.java:68)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:566)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unwrap your connection as it comes from an ironjacamar pool.

Comment: ok. but i'm not sure how to pass back the unwrapped connection back to the ConnectionFactory. because to use this in camel, I need to set the ConnectionFactory back to the org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent

Comment: Without the code being executed i don't know. Somewhere you must have configured the datasource to use

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you ehsavoie. you pointed me to the right direction.

So I have to extend the oracle class to come with the solution:

```
private class OracleAqGetUnderlyingConnectionFactory extends AQjmsConnectionFactory {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   
   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.dataSource = dataSource;
   }
   
   @Override
   public javax.jms.Connection createConnection() throws javax.jms.JMSException {
    WrappedConnectionJDK8 connection = null;
    OracleConnection underlyingOracleConnection = null;
try {
connection = (WrappedConnectionJDK8) dataSource.getConnection();
underlyingOracleConnection = (OracleConnection) connection.getUnderlyingConnection();
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
       return AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(underlyingOracleConnection);
   }

}
```